# PHP Mail Image Template

Tags: php

Here is the code of my email template content (image)

```
$order_query  = $this->db->query("SELECT oi.*,des.image FROM " . DB_PREFIX ."order_items oi
                   LEFT JOIN ".DB_PREFIX ."item_description  des on oi.item_id = des.item_id
                WHERE oi.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id .  "'");

foreach ($order_query ->rows as $orderproduct) {
    $data['orderproduct'] = array();
        $data['orderproduct'][] = array(
            'name' => $orderproduct['name'],
            'image' => $orderproduct['image']

        );
}

foreach ($order_query ->rows as $orderproduct) {
    $text .= $orderproduct['quantity'] . 'x ' . $orderproduct['image'] . "\n";

}



$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol      = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter     = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mail->smtp_port     = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mail->smtp_timeout  = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');
$mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setSubject($language->get(html_entity_decode($language->get('subject_prefix')).' '.$order_info['store_name']));
$mail->setText($text);
$mail->send();
```

The problem that is right now when I receive the email , it showing image link

> https://prnt.sc/r8di9k

how do i display image instead of the file location ?

Comment: There is no code here that would produce an email ???

Comment: Well how would you do it, if you had the image URL, and wanted to show it inside of a normal HTML _page_ instead of an email …? (You will of course have to use an absolute URL here, so you will need to prefix your relative URL with whatever is appropriate.)

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is the part where generate the content . below the code is $mail thingy

Comment: @Micho can we please see your `$mail` thingy.

Comment: And below this code is where the code that places the image into the email would live, so this code is basically irrelevant the code we would need to see is the code you didn't show us :)

Comment: @MarkOverton added the mail code

Comment: You will have to make it an `$mail->isHTML(true);` then put the image into an `<img>` tag

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry for the late reply , when i added this : $mail->IsHTML(true);   i have an error  "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mail::isHTML() "

Comment: Ah, I assumed this was phpMailer code, is it not?

Comment: @RiggsFolly using OpenCart Mail Settings (SMTP)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Need to make a template in HTML and then call image data in src tag

Comment: This it a bit too vague to be really useful to anyone.